# GetElementsByTagName(tag).length

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I tried to count the `<li>`-Elements within an `<ul>`-Listing. I expected it to work like this:

(The JavaScript):

```
var ul = document.getElementById('listing');
function countLi(){
    alert("There are "+ul.getElementsByTagName('li').length+" Li-Elements in this Documnet!");
}
```

(The HTML):

```
<input type="button" onclick="countLi()" value="Count the Li's!"/>
<ul id="listing">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>​
```

It tells me, that "ul is null". So where is my fault?

Kind regards,
vogti

Edit:
Ah, yeah. [I did a Fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/vogti/jNc25/).

Comment: The `ul` isn't in the DOM when your code runs. Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jNc25/1/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that this line:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('listing');
```

is executing before your `ul` exists.  Either move your whole script somewere below your `</ul>`, put your code in a `window.onload`/`$(document).ready` callback, or simply move that line into your function (which will also make your `ul` variable be locally scoped to that function):

```
function countLi(){
    var ul = document.getElementById('listing');
    alert("There are "+ul.getElementsByTagName('li').length+" Li-Elements in this Documnet!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailled explanation. Sometimes its just that easy... :/

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.Listing element not ready when your code block rendered.

```
function countLi(){
    var ul = document.getElementById('listing');
    alert("There are "+ul.getElementsByTagName('li').length+" Li-Elements in this Documnet!");
    }
```

Comment: there is nothing changed here?

Comment: Ah, really had to search for the change :D Now I see, thanks a lot!